# How to get User Object using Twitter Api in Android SDK?

Tags: android, json, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am creating an Android app. I am using Twitter Integration in Android.

**My Need** 
I want to access the User Object from Twitter stated here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object

**My Work** 
I successfully implemented Login using Twitter.

This is my Main Activity Code ::

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key), getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret)))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls

                TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;

                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfilePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("token",token);
                startActivity(intent);






            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
   }
```

**My Issue:** 
Now I want to access the User Object of Twitter Api. I dont know how. Please tell how to call and get the Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An user object can be fetched with an API call via [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
You do not have to include Retrofit explicitly in your project if you have already included the Twitter Kit.

1. Create Retrofit object with the new `OAuth1aInterceptor` provided in the twitter-kit.

   ```
       retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               // Twitter interceptor
               .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                       .addInterceptor(new OAuth1aInterceptor(/*twitter-session*/, /*twitter-auth-config*/))
                       .build())
               .build();
   ```
2. Create an `Interface` for the `Retrofit Client` as usual.

   ```
       import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User;
       import retrofit2.Call;
       import retrofit2.http.GET;
       import retrofit2.http.Query;

       public interface ApiInterface {

           @GET("users/show.json")
           Call<User> getUserDetails(@Query("screen_name") String screenName);

       }
   ```
3. Call the `ApiInterface` function `getUserDetails()`

   ```
       ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
       Call<User> call = apiInterface.getUserDetails(/*screen-name*/);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       });
   ```

**twitter-session :** This can be fetched from `TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession()`.

**twitter-auth-config :** This can be fetched from `TwitterCore.getInstance().getAuthConfig()`

**screen-name :** The `screen-name` i.e the `twitter-handle` of the logged-in user can be fetched from the current active session `/*session*/.getUserName()`

~ Twitter API Reference Index https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index